# Stylus - creating functions in a loop?

Tags: css, iteration, stylus

My question is pretty simple. In my .styl I have:

```
locked-widths(nums)
  for i in 1..nums
    .w-{i}
      $percent = i
      width: $percent+"%"
```

Where nums is a integer normally set to 100 (which gives me classes like .w-1, .w-2, .w-3 and so on).

But what I would like to do is first assigning the CSS width property to a stylus function with the same name as the class, then using that function on the class like so:

```
locked-widths(nums)
  for i in 1..nums
    w-{i}()
      $percent = i
      width: $percent+"%"
    .w-{i}
      w-{i}()
```

..which doesn't work. Do you have any idea if this is possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you can use `define` bif and anonymous functions to accomplish this task:

```
locked-widths(nums)
  for i in 1..nums
    define('w-' + i, @() {
      $percent = i
      width: $percent + '%';
    })

    .w-{i}
      w-{i}()

locked-widths(3)
```

Comment: Thank you Panya. Do you have the reference for it as well in stylus documentation? I can't seem to find it : (

Comment: http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/bifs.html#definename-expr and http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/functions.html#anonymous-functions

Comment: Hello again. The anonymous function method didn't work as expected. It seems like I can't use the function outside the loop (as it's a lambda).

Is this doable? You can read from my example that that's what I want to do. To be able to use:
"w-55()" outside the loop, set to any HTML element through CSS (styl)

Comment: You can define these functions outside the `locked-width` (so they will be global). But I think that you're trying to reinvent placeholder selectors. You can dynamically generate placeholder selectors for each percent and then use `@extend $w-55` inside a group of an element.